# Image brightness, contrast and clarity adjustment order

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm developing an image manipulation software in which the user can adjust brightness, contrast and local contrast/"clarity" of an image.
Adjustments are made using OpenCV's [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) for brightness and contrast, and [CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/db6/classcv_1_1CLAHE.html) for local contrast.

I want to know the order in which I should apply these adjustments to the image. Is there a rule of thumb regarding this ? I get vastly different results changing the order, and I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this question's answer is inside the definitions of those terms.

**Brightness:**  The brightness is directly related with the index values of each pixel. A pixel ( so also an image ) becomes brighter when getting closer to 255(white) and oppositely becomes darker when getting closer to 0(black). This increment or decrease in each pixel is done by adding or subtracting a constant to each pixel.

**Contrast:** In brightness we talked about adding a constant to each pixel, in here we are talking about multiplying each pixel with a constant. This makes gaps between pixels in whole image.

**CLAHE:** I see CLAHE as intelligent of [Histogram Equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization). Some image's pixel population is distributed in a narrow interval inside 0-255. To widen this area to the whole interval(0-255), CLAHE is the tool.

If we back to your question:

- If you set brightness and contrast first, CLAHE can cause a backward
  operation.
- If you use CLAHE first, it can make sense.

**Note:** According to my experiences, CLAHE is mostly used for pre-processing steps. Setting brightness and contrast in low amounts can be okey for both case, but in high amount changing I prefer to set after CLAHE.